# How to return the record that I create it with Create() of Gorm?

Tags: go, go-gorm

How to return the record that I create it with Create() of [Gorm](http://gorm.io/docs/create.html)?

For example,I create a user with `Create()` in the code below:

```
package main

import (
    "apiserver/model"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"
)


func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", "host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 user=postgres dbname=exampledb password=123 sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()   

    db.AutoMigrate(&model.User{})
    user := User{Name: "Jack", Age: 18}
    db.Create(&user)
}
```

I want to return this `user` record,how to do it?

**update:**

Do I need to do it with `Where()`? Like this:

```
db.Where("name = ?", "Jack").First(&user)
```

Comment: Just return the `user` value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [official docs](http://gorm.io/docs/create.html) and [Default value section](http://gorm.io/docs/create.html#Default-Values) after creation, you get all properties updated inside the object. So it should be enough to use the object which reference you passed to `Create`

```
user := User{Name: "Jack", Age: 18}
db.Create(&user)
fmt.Println(user.Name, user.Age)
```

Comment: what about the id field?